# How do I display the Compressed image in ImageView and display its Size?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, image-compression

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "Image" + timestamp + ".jpg");
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/*");
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "Compressed_Images");
                imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
    
            

fos = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
bitmap.compress(WEBP_LOSSY, 10, fos);
            Objects.requireNonNull(fos);
```

Got it displayed in imageview------>

```
 InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                compImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
```

Its Compressing and saving the Image No issue in that

Comment: if you already have the bitmap you shoud be able to just call "setImageBitmap" on an imageview and set the bitmap. You can display the size inside a textview, by calling getWidth and getHeight on the bitmap, making a string out of them and then setting this string as the text of a TextView.

Comment: I understood the logic...... But I have bitmap.compress(WEBP_LOSSY, 10, fos); this as bitmap how do I set it in ImageView......can you help me little in the code

Comment: do you have an image view in your xml code already? You need to call findViewById to get the reference to the imageview and then you call "setImageBitmap" on the imageview with your bitmap as an argument

Comment: A added an answer with a code example down below

Comment: Yess I have imageView in my xml

Comment: Let me give you context a little of what I am doing.....Basically I am taking an Image from Gallery and displaying it in imageview and displaying its size in textview and I used Above Mentioned code to compress and save image that was present in imageview and Now I just want to display the compressed image in another imageview and its size as well

Answer (score 0):

Add an ImageView in the xml layout of your Activity. Like this:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then in your activity's create method you get a reference to that ImageView. Like this:

```
ImageView myImageView = findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
```

And now you call "setImageBitmap" on your imageView with your bitmap as an argument. Like this:

```
myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // "bitmap" is your bitmap
```

If I understood you correctly this should be what you want to do

Comment: Okay...I think you are mistaken between "bitmap" and  "bitmap.compress(WEBP_LOSSY, 10, fos)"....its not possible to set bitmap.compress in imageview

Comment: But you already have the bitmap. Because you are calling compress on it. So it is already loaded in the RAM. So why not use this already loaded image to set it into an image view. Maybe I misunderstand you. But isn't your bitmap object of data type Bitmap?

Comment: Or do you want to first compress the image, by saving it to the output stream and then display the compressed image? Ohhh.

Comment: What you want to do is to open an input stream on your resolver and than read this stream as a new bitmap using BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream is)

Comment: Yess... Absolutely I wanna do it.. Thank you for the quick response ..okay How to do It just give an example..

Comment: InputStream disp = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(disp);
                compImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

Comment: InputStream disp = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(disp);
                compImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

Comment: You could also scale the bitmap down manually and then save the new scaled down Bitmap to storage and display it in your imageview

Comment: Yess I am saving the compressed image in a Folder under Pictures Directory but I don't know how to display the compressed image in imageview because after this:-bitmap.compress(WEBP_LOSSY, 10, fos); image is saved but how to I get that image?

Answer (score 0):

```
 InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            compImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
```

Okay....I was managed to set image in Imageview(I hope its Compressed image)
Now how do I get the size of this?